# Unpack 4 bytes out of int in GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have the following vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

struct Bone
{
    int parent;
    float scale;
    mat4 matrix;
};

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform Bone[67] Bones;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in int boneIndex;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 weight;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 4) in vec2 UVCords;

out vec2 UV;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    UV = UVCords;
}
```

Which I fill up like this (C++):

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)0);  //float position[3]
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)12);    //char boneIndex[4]
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)16); //float weights[4]
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)32); //float normals[3]
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)44); //float textureCords[2]
```

The buffer object which contains the actual data is an array of those:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float position[3];
    char boneIndex[4];
    float weights[4];
    float normals[3];
    float textureCords[2];
};
```

Now, my question is, how can I extract the four bytes from the `int boneIndex` in the GLSL side? Because I know GLSL does not support byte sized types, I guess ill have to extract it to a four different int variables, I just dont know how.

Comment: google gave me first http://www.gamedev.net/topic/556757-unpack-4-bytes-from-an-int-in-glsl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here. First of all, you are not correctly setting up your integer attribute pointer. You have to use `glVertexAttribIPointer` to make the data available as integer in the pipeline.

To acces the single bytes, you can use the standard integer bit shift operations in GLSL, like you could do in C. I recommend using unsigned integers (and unsigned chars), though. So for example accessing the second-highest byte in the value can be done by `(boneIndex >> 16) & 0xff`.